# Can't call a method by using 'this'

Tags: javascript, methods, this

I'm trying to call my method Move(); inside the object MySnake using setInterval:

```
function Snake()
{
    this.Start = function(Speed)
    {
        this.Movement = setInterval(function(){
            this.Move();
        },Speed);
    }
}
var MySnake = new Snake();
MySnake.Start(400); //Doesn't work
```

and this isn't working. But when I call the method through the instance 'MySnake':

```
function Snake() 
{
    MySnake.Start = function(Speed)
    {
        this.Movement = setInterval(function(){
            MySnake.Move();
        },Speed);
    }
}
var MySnake = new Snake();
MySnake.Start(400); //Works
```

I wan't the one whit 'this' keyword to work

Comment: Note that inside the interval callback, `this` is most likely the window, so you're trying to call `window.Move()`, otherwise it seems to work ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TLaR6/

Answer (score 3):

This is because `this` is defined by the caller in JavaScript. The easiest solution is to store it in another variable:

```
function Snake()
{

    this.Start = function(Speed)
    {
        var that = this;
        this.Movement = setInterval(function(){
            that.Move();
        },Speed);
    }
}
var MySnake = new Snake();
MySnake.Start(400); //Work
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybm2Q/). In your example, the inner `this` is the global `window`.

---

Another solution would be to bind `this` in the function to the local `this`, as shown in this [second jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybm2Q/1/):

```
function Snake()
{
    this.Move = function() { document.body.innerHTML += '.'; };

    this.Start = function(Speed)
    {
        this.Movement = setInterval((function(){
            this.Move();
        }).bind(this),Speed);
    }
}
var MySnake = new Snake();
MySnake.Start(400); //Work
```

But this one is harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this.move(); "this" is inside anonymous function passed into the setInterval method, hence you will get an error.

```
function Snake()
{

    this.Start = function(Speed)
    {
        var _this = this;
        this.Movement = setInterval(function(){
            _this.Move();
        },Speed);
    }
}
```

var MySnake = new Snake();

MySnake.Start(400)

This will work since the reference to the object is captured by closure created by the callback for setInterval.